# Any way possible to erase device data - photos - mail - web history on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to make an app that resets or erases the data on the iOS device. The use is for an iPad that will be placed in a public place - school. And after a period of time it should erase all its data. Is there any way possible to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Not possible using any public API.

Comment: As far as I know, programs all run in their own sandbox. Accessing/erasing data, unless specifically allowed is not possible outside the sandbox. And I agree with @rmaddy, for me no public API allows it.

Comment: Maybe an MDM (Mobile Device Management) solution would be more appropriate?
http://www.air-watch.com/solutions/mobile-device-management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible using APIs which would be accepted by Apple.